# Problem with timestamps in Solidity - modifier failing

Tags: solidity

folks. I have a weird issue that has been racking my brain all day. I have isolated it to this bit of code.

In my Crowdfund constructor:

```
 startsAt = now;
 endsAt = 1507852800; // 4 weeks later
```

I also have a modifier:

```
modifier crowdfundIsActive() {
    assert(now > startsAt && now < endsAt);
    _;
}
```

Any function with this modifier fails randomly. I currently have it on my default payable:

```
function () payable crowdfundIsActive {
    buyTokens();
}
```

It fails completely randomly. I can run my truffle tests over and over and over, even pasting the same test in there 20 times, and it will pass half of them and fail half of them. If I remove one of the assertions (ie, the comparison to endsAt or the comparison to startsAt), it still fails randomly.

Here is a picture of the same test failing 3 times and passing once: 
[image: https://gyazo.com/64e0b13207a0d05d96155aa1df54cdc6]

Sometimes it passes all 4 times, sometimes fails all 4, etc.

If I deploy the contract to Ropsten, sending ETH to this function fails. If I remove the modifier, it works fine. What am I missing?

I understand using block.number is more reliable, but time manipulation is not too big of a factor in this code, as it is not a lottery or anything like that. I would like to use timestamps for this.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I fixed it by changing > and < to >= and <=. No idea why this works, as the equals shouldn't be factoring in...

Comment: We have that now = block.timestamp and it is stored as seconds since unix epoch. If block generation is less than 1 second then you can end with two block with the same timestamp.

Comment: It's likely that in your tests some transactions are included in the same block and without the equal sign the condition on the starting time fails. To confirm this, check the block number when you fail the test; also remove the equal sign from the end condition and see if it still works.